# Iphone keyboard and scroll wheel not appearing

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am having trouble with a webview. This webview loads a webpage with some inputfields and some droplists. The problem is that the keyboard and the scroll wheel don't appear. I see a quick 'flash' and the cursor does go in the selected inputfield, but the keyboard doesn't appear.

I'm using xcode 4.3.3

My Appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *windowTB;
    UIViewController *tabBarVC;
//    UIWebView *homeWebView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWindow *windowTB;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIViewController *tabBarVC;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *homeWebView;

@end
```

Appdelegate.m (the relevant part)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "tabBarVC.h"
#import "homeVC.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize windowTB;
@synthesize tabBarVC;
//@synthesize homeWebView;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.windowTB setRootViewController:tabBarVC];

    [self.windowTB makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The homeVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface homeVC : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *homeWebView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *homeWebView;
@end
```

And last homeVC.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "homeVC.h"


@implementation homeVC

@synthesize homeWebView;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [homeWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://rolfdeenen.nl/test.html"]]];
}
```

I have been searching for a about a day now, but it just doesn't make sence to me. Can anyone help me?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in your webpage, because the webview has a standard behavior and you can't modify it.

Comment: My webpage is just a standard test webpage, http://rolfdeenen.nl/test.html There is nothing special there. Or is there something missing?

Comment: I have changed the website to google, but the problem remains

Comment: Did you set `userInteractionEnabled = YES` for your webview ?

Comment: In the Interface builder I have checked the User Interaction Enabled button and I have added [homeWebView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; to homeVC.m. Still no luck I'm affraid